# Custom search php for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i got an warning like this "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource", how can i fix this?
Thanks!

```
global $wpdb;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db('search');

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchquery']));
$sqlCommand = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_doctors` WHERE `name` LIKE '%searchquery%'");


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlCommand)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $spec = $row['spec'];
    echo "Nume: $name<br />Specializare: $spec";
}
```

Comment: You are mixing mysqli_ and mysql_

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for this ,

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlCommand)`

$wpdb->get_results already did the job just `var_dump $sqlCommand` and you will see the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Mulitple row results can be pulled from the database with get_results. The function returns the entire query result as an array,

So you could make this change in your code:

```
global $wpdb;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db('search');

$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchquery']));
$sqlCommand = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_doctors` WHERE `name` LIKE '%searchquery%'");

foreach ( $sqlCommand as $result) 
{
    echo $result->id;
        echo $result->name;
        echo $result->spec;
}
```

Comment: Now it give me this "Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"...damn it

Comment: Fixed the last warning. Another question: what can i do to see the results in the same page?